# Why is Samba using massive amounts of RAM?

Tags: memory, debian, samba

On Debian 4.2.10, Samba is using massive amounts of RAM when copying a few large files and lots of smaller ones. How do I resolve this, as I'm really close to writing a `cron` job to restart `smbd` every 24 hours?

```ini
PID   USER  PR  NI     VIRT     RES   SHR   S   %CPU  %MEM      TIME+   COMMAND
1272  root  20   0  3829868  3.312g  1860   D    0.7  93.0  512:39.94      smbd
```

- `free -m`:

  ```ini
                      total   used   free   shared    buffers   cached
                Mem:   3644   3560     84        7          0       25
  -/+ buffers/cache:   3533    110     # <--- this is what bugs me
               Swap:   4292   2146   2146
  ```
- Config:

  ```ini
  [global]
    server role               = standalone server
    map to guest              = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions     = Yes
    pam password change       = Yes
    passwd program            = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat               = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync        = Yes
    syslog                    = 0
    log file                  = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size              = 1000
    dns proxy                 = No
    usershare allow guests    = Yes
    panic action              = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend  = tdb

  [homes]
    comment         = Home Directories
    valid users     = %S
    create mask     = 0700
    directory mask  = 0700
    browseable      = No

  [printers]
    comment         = All Printers
    path            = /var/spool/samba
    create mask     = 0700
    printable       = Yes
    print ok        = Yes
    browseable      = No

  [print$]
    comment         = Printer Drivers
    path            = /var/lib/samba/printers

  [media]
    # Unsure what this is, but it was a working share at one time
    path            = /rem/media/

  [rem]
    path            = /rem/
    force user      = <rem owner username here>
    read only       = No
    create mask     = 0660
    directory mask  = 0770
  ```

Restarting the `smbd` service seems to solve the problem, but it keeps coming back after ~2hrs:

- After stopping the `smbd` service, everything seems okay:

  ```ini
                      total   used   free   shared    buffers   cached
                Mem:   3644    123   3521        8          3       36
  -/+ buffers/cache:     83   3561
               Swap:   4292    230   4062
  ```
- It seems as though Samba isn't reading/writing anything while eating RAM:

  ```ini
   TID  PRIO  USER  DISK READ   DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO>   COMMAND
  1351  be/4  root   0.00 B/s     3.95 K/s  0.00 %   0.00 %   smbd -D
  ```

The problem is half-solved using @Hastur's advice and am waiting for clients to go ahead and index/scan/do whatever with their Samba share

- Current status:

  ```ini
    PID   USER  PR  NI    VIRT    RES     SHR   S   %CPU  %MEM      TIME+   COMMAND
  18992   root  20   0  283140   8916    6584   S    1.0   0.2    0:00.32      smbd
  18983   root  20   0  284048  14964   11752   S    0.7   0.4    0:00.16      smbd
  ```

  Interestingly, later it consumes both RAM and CPU::

  ```ini
    PID   USER  PR  NI    VIRT    RES     SHR   S   %CPU  %MEM      TIME+   COMMAND
  18983   root  20   0 2964080 2.564g    6044   R   92.1  72.0  853:58.94      smbd
  ```

I limited the number of file locks & connections, with little change; it's still using RAM like crazy but did suddenly decrease CPU usage:

- ```ini
     PID   USER  PR  NI    VIRT    RES     SHR   S   %CPU  %MEM      TIME+   COMMAND
   24606   root  20   0 3768932 3.325g    2332   D   17.3  93.4    1441:50      smbd
  ```

Comment: Your question is missing important details. What distribution? What version of Samba? What type of access pattern is Samba seeing? Many large files? Many small files? And also of course: What’s the question?

Comment: The question is: Why is samba eating that much ram? Distro: debian, in case you can't read tags :P Version: 4.2.10-Debian Access pattern? No idea what that is :P Large files: Not much, just 2-3 pcs. of 4GB files, Small files: A LOT.

Comment: Did you try to see if all that ram usage decreases with samba active and internet physically disconnected? The implied guess is that some one  is indexing from outside your _tribes_ of little files. BTW how many  are them? (`find . | wc -l`). Even more how many in a single directory? If they are too many you can divide in more subpath...

Comment: Files are in separate subdirectories (categorized by date), but actually, I think I'm going to try disconnecting from the internet once the problem appears again.

Comment: @Hastur BTW, there you go, output of `find . | wc -l`: `24128` (Executed from samba share root (`/rem/`))

Comment: Not so few. If someone mount your samba directory or scan searching for virus it can eat a lot of memory. Check too the directory with the bigger number of files (`QQ ()  { for i in "$@" ; do ( AA=$(ls "$i" | wc -l); printf "%6.6d %s \n" $AA "$i"; );   done; }` then `QQ /rem/*/ | tail -n 3 `). Look in samba.cfg for example search for  `max stat cache size`, `write cache size`

Comment: Check if you mind [this page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html) for all the possible sources related with 25k files.

Comment: Well... see the updated question, but in a nutshell the problem is probably solved.

Comment: @Hastur No, unfortunate news. :/ It's eating a little less ram than it used to, but it's eating my CPU now.

Answer (score 0):

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION!**
This isn't the actual way to solve this problem, but it works out perfectly for me.

1. `(sudo) crontab -e`.
2. Choose `nano` or `vim` according to your preference. (If you haven't chose it already)
3. In the file, add the line `0 [whatever hour (0-23) you want here] * * * service smbd restart`

This will restart the `smbd` (Samba daemon) service on an every day basis.

As I said, **this is not the final solution**, so if anyone has better solutions, THEN I'll accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, we have a Samba share on Debian 11 running Samba version 4.14 and we were having the same issue. What happens, at least for us, is that Samba doesn't clear the files it has cached in RAM. This was causing all of our RAM and swap to fill up and then the server crashed. This happened a few times, even causing some data corruption, which was a mess.

Anyways, to be safe, find out how long it takes to fill up your RAM under a heavy work load. For us, we figured this out by uploading/downloading many gigabytes of pictures and videos to Samba from multiple clients and also doing Time Machine backups on every Mac on out network. The answer for us was about an hour.

**Important note:** Run `systemctl status smbd` to see the RAM usage. For us, `top` and `htop` did not accurately show how much RAM Samba was using.

Once you get that number, cut the time in half (for us, 30 mins) and run this command in crontab every 30 mins:

```
sync; sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I don't have the best understanding of the nuances of these commands, but this is what I can tell you:

The `sync` command commits everything that is in RAM to disk, assuming that its final destination is disk. Run the `sync` command twice to make sure everything is committed. The command `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` flushes some of the cache in RAM. We tried running the command every minute just to test the stability of it while doing file transfers, and it was fine.

I hope this resolves the issue!!